# Error in Liquid templating when including non-english (UTF-8) filenamed files

Tags: jekyll, shopify, liquid, liquid-layout

I have a html file in a non-english langauge ( മലയാളം.html ). If I try to include this html file using the below code, I am getting the below shown error.

```
{% include blog_comments/മലയാളം.html %}
```

By the way I am using Jekyll. But I believe the error is from Liquid

> Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2016-05-05 09:49:14 Liquid
>   Exception: Invalid syntax for include tag. File contains invalid
>   characters or sequences: blog_comments/മലയാളം.html Valid syntax: {%
>   include file.ext param='value' param2='value' %} in
>   _includes/post_comments.html, included in _layouts/post.html

Does anyone know how to get the file മലയാളം.html included ?

Comment: I'm not sure if `blog_comments/മലയാളം.html` itself is the right syntax. As far as I know you can use `include` to `include` only snippets having ".liquid" extension and nothing else. More on it here - https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/theme-tags#include

Comment: Jekyll doesn't use Liquid include tag but its own flavor at https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/3.0-stable/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read [jekyll/tags/include.rb code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/3.0-stable/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb#L58), you can see that file names are validated against a regular expression, which main part is :

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\/\.-]+$/
```

That means that **includes names** cannot contain something else than european alphabet letters (lower or upper case), numbers or /, _ , - and .

You will have to rename it to `blog_comments/Malayalam.html` ;-)

**Note**: You can have a page or a collection item (including posts) with a name containing `മലയാളം`